# R: aggregate rows to transform monthly into quarterly data

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, tidyverse, aggregate

I have a dataframe with monthly observations. Each row represents a month.
I need to transform it into a dataframe with quarterly observations. In other words, I need to aggregate months 1-3 to form Q1, 4-6 for Q2, etc.

```
survey1 <- data.frame("col1" = c(10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20),
                     "col2" = c(10, 15, 12, 30, 33, 35),
                     "col3" = c(12, 12, 12, 22, 22, 22))
```

It gets trickier since I want to aggregate columns with different operations.

Column1 and column 3 are constant during each quarter: they have the same values for month 1, month 2, and month 3.

On the other hand, column 2 does record different values for each month. I would like to sum up all the values of column 2 for each quarterly observation of the new dataframe.

In other words, I want to get from **survey1** above to **survey2** below.

```
survey2 <- data.frame("col1" = c(10, 20),
                     "col2" = c(37, 98),
                     "col3" = c(12, 22))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may divide every 3 rows into one quarter and calculate the summarising statistics for each variable. Since `col1` and `col3` have the same value in each quarter we can select any value from those columns, I have selected the 1st one.

```
library(dplyr)

survey1 %>%
  group_by(Quarter = paste0('Q', ceiling(row_number()/3))) %>%
  summarise(across(c(col1, col3), first), 
            col2 = sum(col2)) %>%
  select(Quarter, col1, col2, col3)

#  Quarter  col1  col2  col3
#  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 Q1         10    37    12
#2 Q2         20    98    22
```

---

A hack can also be to use `col1` and `col3` as grouping variable since we know they are the same every quarter. This would work provided every quarter has a different value for `col1` and `col3` combination.

```
survey1 %>% 
    group_by(col1, col3) %>% 
    summarise(col2 = sum(col2), .groups = 'drop')
```

Comment: Hi. Is there any way to have this command without creating a new variable for quarters?

Answer (score 2):

I provided alternative solution

1. create a mock month's column (dynamically expands by row of data)
2. then create quarter column
3. group_by quarter
4. For cols1&3 take the minimum values since it doesn't change
5. for cols2 take the sum

```
survey1 %>% 
  mutate(months=1:dim(survey1)[1],
         quarter=lubridate::quarter(months)) %>% 
  group_by(quarter) %>% 
  summarize(col1_min=min(col1),
            col2_sum=sum(col2),
            col3_min=min(col3))
```